# Can't install python-tools without encountering exception

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install python tools so that I can install xlsxtocsv program, but am encountering problems. I think they are related to my percona installation, but can't be sure how to resolve this issue. Help would be greatly appreciated.

`root@laptop:/home/jay/programs/testcsv# sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.6.24-1ubuntu14.04)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@laptop:/home/jay/programs/testcsv# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/230 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,339 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 208817 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.6.24-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.6.24-1ubuntu14.04) over (5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.6.24-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys', which is also in package percona-server-server-5.6 5.6.23-72.1-1.trusty
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.6.24-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: try `apt-get clean` `apt-get -f install` and then  `dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Also try **`sudo apt-get update`** before apt-get -f install

Comment: These suggestions don't work. I'm still encountering issues.